# Only show family names in citation and bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I'd like to only show family names (of authors, editors, ...) both in citations and the bibliography when using biblatex and biber. I already tried:

```
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameaffix}[1]{}
```

But this leaves extra spaces where the omitted parts were. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details will depend on the style (which you don't show in the question), but the general approach should be as follows.

First we define a name format that prints only the family name. Then we tell `biblatex` to use this new format for the `default` format, `sortname` (the primary name associated with the work, usually the `author` or `editor`, in `authoryear`- and `authortitle`-like bibliographies) and `labelname` (the format in `authoryear`- and `authortitle`-like citations).

Depending on your style not all of these might be necessary, it is also possible that you need to redefine even more name formats.

If you unconditionally suppress given names, you should make sure the `uniquename` feature is turned off with `uniquename=false` (again, if you have to do this depends on the style).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber, uniquename=false]{biblatex}


\DeclareNameFormat{family}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:family}
    {\namepartfamily}
    {\namepartgiven}
    {\namepartprefix}
    {\namepartsuffix}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}
\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{default}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson,cicero,gaonkar:in}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Citations and bibliography only with family names.]

Comment: Thanks, worked great!